# Repeat jquery statement using while loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, while-loop

I am new to JavaScript/jQuery. I have a script file linked to a page. I am trying to repeat a simple jQuery statement using while loop in the file. Below are the codes sample. How can I repeat them in while loop?

The codes:

```
e(".rwpt_testimonials .rwpt_quotes ul li:nth-child(1)").addClass("quote_1");
e(".rwpt_testimonials .rwpt_quotes ul li:nth-child(2)").addClass("quote_2");
e(".rwpt_testimonials .rwpt_quotes ul li:nth-child(3)").addClass("quote_3");
e(".rwpt_testimonials .rwpt_quotes ul li:nth-child(4)").addClass("quote_4");
e(".rwpt_testimonials .rwpt_quotes ul li:nth-child(5)").addClass("quote_5");
e(".rwpt_testimonials .rwpt_quotes ul li:nth-child(6)").addClass("quote_6");
e(".rwpt_testimonials .rwpt_quotes ul li:nth-child(7)").addClass("quote_7");
e(".rwpt_testimonials .rwpt_quotes ul li:nth-child(8)").addClass("quote_8");
e(".rwpt_testimonials .rwpt_quotes ul li:nth-child(9)").addClass("quote_9");
e(".rwpt_testimonials .rwpt_quotes ul li:nth-child(10)").addClass("quote_10");
```

I am trying but not working:

```
var i = 0;
while( i < 10 ) {
return 'e(".rwpt_testimonials .rwpt_photos ul li:nth-child(' + i + ')").addClass("quote_' + i + '");';
  i++;
}
```

Comment: You should look into jQuery's `each` method. Something like this: `$('.rwpt_testimonials .rwpt_quotes ul li').each(function(idx){ $(this).addClass('quote' +  idx)})`

Comment: Do it with each.. But I wonder the context of the code.. if you could likely rethink it so you don't have to iterate over so many elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery method `.each()` to iterate through each list item.

JS (jQuery):

```
$('.rwpt_testimonials .rwpt_quotes ul li').each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass('quote_'+(i+1));
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flowstoneknight/6297r34q/).

Answer (score 0):

[`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) is only used in functions to return a value. Here you can just straight up execute `e`:

```
var i = 0;
while( i < 10 ) {
    e(".rwpt_testimonials .rwpt_photos ul li:nth-child(" + i + ")").addClass("quote_" + i);
    i++;
}
```

However, a [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop (instead of `while`) is generally used when you know how many times you're going to be looping:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    e(".rwpt_testimonials .rwpt_photos ul li:nth-child(" + i + ")").addClass("quote_" + i);
}
```

You may want to rethink about what you're doing though, for the sake of efficiency and maintainability.